# In which part of logstash can I put the mapping of an elasticsearch index?

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I want to configure the mapping of an `Elasticsearch` index in the `pipeline.conf` file of `Logstash`. Is it in the `input`, or in the `filter`, or in the `output` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would configure the mapping using a [template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-manage_template) in the elasticsearch output.